# O português é considerado muito complexo por especialistas da língua?

Tags: linguística, linguagem

Primeiro gostaria de esclarecer porque tal pergunta pode ser relevante. Medidas de complexidade permitem, se não uma precisa predição, ao menos a elaboração de estimativas associadas a um fenômeno de interesse. Para dar um exemplo, se nosso interesse fosse saber de antemão o tempo de apredizado necessário para se atingir a fluência de uma língua, conhecer o quão complexa esta língua é pode aumentar nossas chances de estimativas mais precisas.

O caso das linguagens de programação servem, inclusive, de exemplo concreto. Muitos concordarão que C é mais simples (com menos elementos) e portanto mais trabalhoso do que Python para tarefas mais rotineiras do programador, como a elaboração de protótipos. Outros concordarão, intuitivamente, que linguagens de programação são mais simples (com menos elementos) do que as diversas línguas primeiras (e aqui admito ser no mínimo improvável que alguém tenha uma linguagem de programação como língua primeira).

Não estou seguro a respeito de quais os especialistas mais habilitados para responder essa pergunta. Seriam os linguistas, gramáticos, etimólogos (e assim por diante)?

Talvez essa pergunta possa parecer muito ampla à primeira vista e impossível de se responder sem uma comparação com outras línguas, pois perguntar se algo seria "muito", "mais", "menos", parece implicar isso. Mas me parece possível evitá-la, ao menos incialmente. Permita-me explicar.

Talvez seja mesmo possível de tatear essa pergunta sem comparar com outras línguas e assim evitar um trabalho desproporcional para a presente ocasião. Comecemos, pois, por elencar indicadores de complexidade. Por exemplo, número de inflexões, verbos irregulares, frequência de exceções de regras gerais (perdão por não utilizar os termos técnicos, não sou um especialista). Isso já seria um ponto de partida para uma eventual comparação.

Aproveito a ocasião para perguntar se existem trabalhos especializados sobre o assunto, especificamente sobre o português.

Comment: Tu contradizes-te. Pegando no teu exemplo, eu diria que C é certamente mais simples do que Python (a linguagem tem poucas estruturas e abstrações comparativamente a linguagens de mais alto nível como Python ou C++). Se é mais difícil prototipar (o que mesmo assim, enfim, dependerá da aplicação) é precisamente porque é mais simples. Da mesma forma, a quantidade de "elementos" que a linguagem tem não está (necessariamente) ligado a quão fácilmente alguém se exprime numa língua. Antes talvez pelo contrário, menos elementos -> mais ambiguidade, mais nuances.

Comment: Você está correto. O fato é que não usei o mesmo sistema de medidas!

Comment: Realmente parece ser muita ampla.

Comment: Eu pensei sobre a amplitude e por isso fiz questão de restringir o escopo ao máximo indicando três maneiras de responder a pergunta (pelo menos em parte). 1) Enumerar critérios de complexidade ou 2) referências de estudos sobre o tema não restringe mais a pergunta? 3) Indicar os especialistas que estão estudando o assunto.

Comment: @cpicanço: Tenho que começar por admitir que não sei puto deste assunto. Mas encontrei [este estudo](https://www.google.pt/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCUQFjABahUKEwiEvpLy9MvIAhXF2BoKHYVGADI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww2.ling.su.se%2Fstaff%2Foesten%2Fpresentations%2Fequalcomplex.ppt&usg=AFQjCNEY7iFm3oLFtapDtjRzI2u_j35exQ&bvm=bv.105454873,d.bGg) comparativo da complexidade de dois dialetos suecos. É acessível, em 41 slides, e dá uma ideia de como se pode avaliar a complexidade.

Comment: @cpicanço: Aprendi no estudo anterior que existe *complexidade objetiva* e *complexidade sentida pelo sujeito*, que é a que interessa para prever o tempo necessário para a aprendizagem. Para um falante de português, hebreu é mais complexo que espanhol; para um árabe é capaz de ser o contrário. Um instituto dos EUA tem [esta ordenação das línguas](http://www.effectivelanguagelearning.com/language-guide/language-difficulty) por tempo necessário para um falante nativo de inglês aprender. O português está entre as mais fáceis de aprender! Á frente do alemão.

Comment: @Jacinto, acho que organizando essas informações, já daria uma boa resposta não? Se acha que convém, sinta-se livre para responder.

Comment: Só os verbos são complicadíssimos, e há muitas palavras com o mesmo significado mas que só se atribuem em contextos específicos. O vocabulário português é muito extenso e variado.

Comment: Eu compreendo a pergunta, mas ainda acho que é muio ampla pra ser respondida no formato Q&A proposto aqui. Acho a pergunta muito interessante, mas ela precisa ser dividida em duas ou mais questões separadas.

Comment: @cpicanco em relação ao português em específico não me surgiu nada, mas encontrei um _paper_ académico chamado Evaluating Linguistic Difficulty (http://thormay.net/lxesl/tech4.html) que aborda muitas das questões que levantaste.

Comment: @cpicanco adicionalmente, podes tentar procurar informação acerca de um senhor chamado Noam Chomsky - https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noam_Chomsky - que é uma das maiores referências de um certo sector da linguística (que me parece mais relevante face ao tipo de questões que levantaste).

Comment: Queria também dizer que não concordo com a tua primeira frase, pois partes do princípio que _fluência_ é um estado finito e quantificável, que não me parece que seja. Acima de qualquer outra contribuição (não me levem a mal, por favor) acho que a contribuição mais válida que houve aqui foi a do @James quando sugeriu partir a questão em pedaços mais pequenos...

Comment: Olá @Joum, sugerir que *fluência* pode ser quantificada (o que é feito frequentemente por testes como o TOEFL) não implica necessariamente que "fluência" seja finita; a saber, podemos delimitar um critério de desempenho de 10 em uma escala de 0 a infinito. Isto é, a partir de 10 você é fluente... acima de 10 cada vez mais fluente... Quantificar também não significa necessariamente filiar-se a uma tradição que considera o valor motivacional de "notas" maior do que o valor motivacional "do conhecimento em si mesmo"....

Comment: @Joum, sim, concordo com a sugestão de James, mas infelizmente não vejo claramente como "fatiar" essa pergunta... nem você nem James fizeram questão de expor quais questões adicionais seriam essas...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

É complicado falar em dificuldade para aprender um idioma, sem compará-lo com outros, visto que o conhecimento prévio de outro(s) idioma(s) deve influenciar na facilidade de compreensão do novo idioma. Um exemplo deste fato pode ser visto [neste artigo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propaedeutic_value_of_Esperanto) que mostra que o aprendizado de Esperanto facilita o aprendizado posterior de outros idiomas.

Isso sem falar que *aprender* um idioma consiste, no mínimo, em 4 diferentes aspectos: leitura, escrita, conversação e escuta que podem ter dificuldades variadas. [Este artigo](http://www.lingholic.com/hardest-languages-learn/) ilustra, p.ex. que mandarim costuma ser considerado muito difícil por conta de sua escrita, mas não tão difícil de ser falado. Por outro lado, o aprendizado de *Hagul* (sistema de escrita usado no coreano) pode ser aprendido em questão de horas ou dias, mas falar o idioma coreano é algo completamente diferente.

Apesar disso, existe um ranking *oficial* sobre a dificuldade de aprendizado de outros idiomas por falantes nativos do Inglês (único ranking que pude achar). Este ranking é elaborado pelo *Foreign Service Institute (FSI)* do Departamento de Estado Norte-Americano. Nele, os idiomas são colocados em 4 níveis diferentes de dificuldade e o Português se enquadra no 1o grupo (o mais fácil). O ranking pode ser sumarizado na imagem que segue ao final.

O Português é de origem latina, pertencendo à família dos [idiomas indo-europeus](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%ADnguas_indo-europeias), assim possui semelhanças com diversos outros idiomas de mesma origem (espanhol, francês, italiano, romeno...). Mesmo que o inglês, pertença ao grupo lingüistico [germânico](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%ADnguas_germ%C3%A2nicas) enquanto o Português pertence ao [itálico](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%ADnguas_it%C3%A1licas) não parece ser complicado para falantes nativos aprenderem a [última flor do Lácio](http://www.releituras.com/olavobilac_lingua.asp). Assim sendo, creio que a resposta para a pergunta "O Português é considerado muito complexo por especialistas da língua?" é **não**!

[image: FSI ranking on language difficulty]

Comment: Tu salientas o inglês e português terem origens diferentes (se recuares só uns 4 ou 5 milhares de anos; são ambas indo-europeias) para concluíres que o português não é complexo, mas na figura o português está incluído nas línguas «closely related to English».

Comment: @Jacinto, Mesmo pertencendo à mesma família indo-europeia, eu quis ressaltar que ambos idiomas têm origem em grupos llingüisticos distintos, sendo o Portugues do grupo [itálico](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%ADnguas_itálicas) e o Inglês do [Germânico](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%ADnguas_germânicas). Creio que o "closely related" da figura se refere a semelhanças gramaticais e sintáticas dos idiomas comparados ao Inglês. E podem existir tais semelhanças mesmo entre idiomas de diferentes origens.Vou editar o último parágrafo da minha resposta acima para deixar isto mais claro, Ok?

Comment: Uma resposta interessante.